# Github Actions `runs-on` self-hosted runner if ubuntu-latest is not available

Tags: github-actions

We are usually using default `ubuntu-latest` runner for GitHub Actions workflows.

But sometimes, because of payment problems default runner is not available. In this case I want to turn on self-hosted instance and use it to be able run workflows.

**The question is:** what is a possible solution to do it?

The closer solution that I able to do is:

```yaml
...
jobs:
  job-name:
    name: Job Name
    # check if repository's description topics value is ["self-hosted"] to determine runner
    runs-on: ${{ contains(github.event.repository.topics, 'self-hosted') && 'self-hosted' || 'ubuntu-latest' }}
...
```

1. I have to power on self-hosted runner
2. I have to add `self-hosted` topic to repository description
3. Profit

It is simple and should work, but here are two problems:

1. This method is not fully automated (GitHub can't determine correct runner by itself)
2. `github` [context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) is not updating on [`Re-run Job`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/re-running-workflows-and-jobs#re-running-failed-jobs-in-a-workflow) so `topics` won't be updated and it is not possible to restart failed job with another runner

So, I'm looking for a solution how to update context for existent jobs (to solve at least second problem) or trying to find is it possible to check if `self-hosted` is running and use it if yes (to solve both problems).

Comment: Did you try using something like this: `runs-on: ${{ github.event.repository.default_branch == 'main' && github.run_number == 1 && 'ubuntu-latest' || 'self-hosted' }}`? With this configuration, the workflow will attempt to use the `ubuntu-latest` runner when it is available, but will use a `self-hosted` runner if the `ubuntu-latest` runner is not available or does not meet the job's requirements.

Comment: In the expression I shared above, the `runs-on` expression checks if the workflow is running on the main branch (`github.event.repository.default_branch == 'main'`) and if it is the first run of the workflow (`github.run_number == 1`). If both conditions are true, the expression uses `ubuntu-latest` as the runner. Otherwise, it falls back to using a `self-hosted` runner. It's exactly the same context as yours, but the solution might be similar to what you want to achieve.

Comment: @GuiFalourd 1. `github.event.repository.default_branch` is a default branch but not affected branch. My default branch is `develop` so this check will be always `false` even if I will merge into `main`. 2. `github.run_number` is an interesting parameter that is changing on retry. But I don't want to fall back to `self-hosted` at **any** retry. For example, if it possible to update `github` context (and use it) if `run_number != 1` that will be really helpful

Comment: I don't think it's possible to update the github context on retry. You would probably have to create a new event in that case.